# Django JWT auth without migration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have 2 projects written by Django : 1- Authentication(P1) and 2- my_API(P2). in P1 I use DRF-simplejwt and 'dj-rest-auth' to register,login,logout,reset password ,... for P2 I need authentication. My opinion is that JWT does not use database for checking access token so It does not need to connect my users' db to P2. But now I have error saying that I should migrate auth_user for rest_framework_simplejwt. What should I do now for checking permissions of P2 end points? I also mention that I set both of SECRET_KEYs to the same value. Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

The rest_framework_simplejwt plugin uses the User model for authentication and other stuff, even if you don' t perform authentication in the my_API project, you need to migrate the User model (is a requirement). I advice you to create a single project with two applications.